# SmartWatch 2 change menu icon on runtime

Tags: menu, icons, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to change the Icon of a menu item after its clicked.  (I am talking about the action menu which deploys on the Action key press)

This is what I have so far:

```
@Override
public void onMenuItemSelected(final int menuItem) {        
    if (menuItem == MENU_ITEM_START) {  
        if(!Started){
            Started=true;
            **Intent intent = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_MENU_SHOW);
            intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_ID,MENU_ITEM_START);
            intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_MENU_ITEM_ICON, ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.menu_item_stop));
            sendToHostApp(intent);**            

            mHandler.postDelayed(RunnableObject, 1000);
        }
        else{
            Started=false;              
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(RunnableObject);
        }
    }

}
```

So, I added the bolded code  (between ** and **), to start an intent to "change" the icon in the same way I create the menu the first time, however, that wont work.

Maybe wrong intent: **CONTROL_MENU_SHOW**??  That is the one I found in the Control Class when initializing the menu.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I found a workaround, which is using two menu objects and toggle them, however, is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no way to do it directly.  The way you are doing it is the only way.